# QGIS - Group by expression in attributes form completion

Tags: qgis

With `QGIS 3.22.4` I build a relational value between two tables: a reference table (called *`culture`* here) and a geographical layer (called *`field`* here). In my reference table, I have several features who sometimes have the same *`culture`* value.

[image: reference_table]

In my geographical layer, I configure a relational value in the attributes form to display *`culture`* value from *`culture`* table in the *`crop`* field. I activate auto completion mode to help users.

[image: attributes_form]

When I edit or create a feature, I have the same repeated values

[image: editing]

Can I group them ? I only want to display unique values.

Edit: I found [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189750/how-to-group-by-attributes-and-give-unique-categories-in-qgis), with a query and virtual layer but a solution may exist without this extra table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this expression (QGIS 3.22) in the 'Filter expression' part of your Value Relation widget -

```
$id=array_first(array_agg($id,"culture"))
```

It groups the feature id value from the other layer by the desired column, then just grabs the feature with the first id value from that list. The list is therefore filtered to just the first instance of each `"culture"` value. It's similar to the 'first value' aggregate that is present in several languages/tools, I'm not sure if Q 3.24 has introduced this as its own function.

I'm not sure if it will be very efficient if the source table is quite large though.

Example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you know your source layer will be updated regularly/dynamically, `$id` (QGIS interpreted feature id) can be a little unpredictable (esp with unsaved features), so instead of using `$id` in the above expression, you could also use a column from the source layer that you know will be unique and non-null every time a new feature is created (e.g. `"uuid"` or `"id"`)

Comment: Light and efficient solution. I was sure QGIS could do it. Thanks.